# Building a floating rate on the tokens

Tags: tokens

For example. I can make a static price.

```
 function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
    buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
}
```

But how can make a floating price.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ethereum VM does not support floating point operations currently.

What you can do is to use a divisor in your calculations.

Eg:

```
uint256 divisor = 1000000;
uint256 sellPrice = 1234; // To represent 0.001234
uint256 buyPrice = 1123;  // To represent 0.001123
uint256 amount = 1 ether;
uint256 sellAmount = amount * sellPrice / divisor;
```

You can see this technique being used in [buy()](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/blob/3d5b4d69ad1be5816fd39b74bd0a40e7c31a2de0/contracts/TokenSellerFactory#L97-L116) function of [GNTTokenTrader](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/blob/3d5b4d69ad1be5816fd39b74bd0a40e7c31a2de0/contracts/TokenSellerFactory) to represent the "floating point" prices in https://cryptoderivatives.market/.

Here is a Browser Solidity screen demonstrating the calculations:
[image]

Comment: Just updated with a Browser Solidity screenshot demonstrating the calculations.