# How should I multiply ether by a decimal?

Tags: solidity

I'd like to multiply Ether by a decimal (a proportion, e.g. 0.05). I've got:

```
ufixed proportion; // What type should proportion be?

function functionName() {
  var Ether = msg.value; // (in units of wei)
  var proportionOfEther = Ether * proportion
  ...
```

My Solidity linter is saying that `*` is not compatible with uint256 (the Ether) and ufixed128x128 (the proportion).

Comment: msg.value is in Wei not Ether. It should be quite a big number, because Wei are very small. Life is easier if you just avoid decimals, eg store your proportion as percent, divide by 100 and multiply by it.

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/building-a-floating-rate-on-the-tokens for an example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of multiplying by a decimal, multiply and divide by integers.

i.e. `(Ether * 5)/100`

Comment: This is exactly what you should do, but be certain to use the parens to do it in the order shown. If you divide first, I think you would get a different result due to truncation. Also, if I were you, I would be careful to think in terms of wei, not ether. The assignment var Ether = msg.value is already a bit off (at least the name of the variable is) because msg.value is in wei. You comments says that, but the variable name disagrees. A minor point, I know, but when dealing with this stuff, you have to be super careful in my experience.

Comment: ^This is important. Whenever possible, avoid using Ether as a unit. It is far easier to reason about an integer quantity of Wei than a fractional quantity of ether.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush TjadenHess Thank you, I have changed the variable names to wei. I was using Ether to refer to the currency, not the denomination, but that isn't important.

Comment: also you should note that the names`ether`, `wei`, `finney`, etc. are reserved in Solidity. (`ether == 10**18`,  `finney == 10**15`, etc.)

Comment: If I have 7 Ether, then the result will be 0.35. At any rate, it will get chopped off as a zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DS-Math](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math) (I answered that [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/55954/31781) in more detail)

Answer (score 0):

fixed point math does not work in solidity yet.

See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html

That is why you need to use the methods listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `mulu` function from [ABDK Math 64.64 library](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L180).  It multiplies uint value by 64.64-bit fixed point number.